# access javascript variable from another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, global-variables

I have the following structure

```
// script1.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var somevar;
    $('somelem').myPlugin();
});


// script2.js

(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        // access and modify 'somevar' here so that it gets modified
        // in the function which called a plugin

    };
});
```

- I want the 'somevar' variable to get modified by plugin and I would
  be able to work with already modified variable further in the plugin
  caller function's scope.
- I do not want to use global variable.
- I see no use of passing the variable as an option to a plugin as it
  would become local to a plugin function and modifying would not
  modify the original variable as I understand.
- I may misunderstand the concept of how javascript works, so any
  answer appreciated.

Comment: Javascript scope can be quite complicated and I don't use Jquery, but to me it looks like the somevar variable has local scope as it's contained within an anonymous function and you've instantiated it with 'var'.

Comment: @jayp Sure, it's local. That actually is a problem the question is about. I do not want to make it global. Making it global solves the question, but, as I can see, causes a memory leak in IE, because 'somevar' conatains a large amount of data in my real script and IE doesn't seem to manage it right.

Comment: Have a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830496/jquery-make-global-variable-available-to-multiple-plugins

Comment: You could create a class, create an instance of the class and then use that to contain somevar and your other data. That way the global scope won't be polluted and you will be able to access the class properties / methods from wherever you like. The class itself will have to be accessible globally, though.

Comment: ManseUK - that is a nifty workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a primitive type, it is passed by value. But, if you pass an object then it'll pass by reference. So, you can do that -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var somevar = {val: 5};
    $(document).myPlugin(somevar);
    alert(somevar.val);
});


// script2.js

(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        options.val ++;
        // access and modify 'somevar' here so that it gets modified
        // in the function which called a plugin

    };
})(jQuery);
```

see the live demo :: http://jsfiddle.net/rifat/EdRFm/

Comment: Works as expected for now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a singleton class for your global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the plugin function return a value and assign that to somevar

```
somevar = $('someelem').myPlugin();
```

Or you could pass an callback as parameter to your plugin method

```
// Script 1
var somevar;
$('someelem').myPlugin(function(newValue) {
    somevar = newValue;
});

// Script 2
$.fn.myPlugin = function(callback) {
    ...
    callback(newValueForSomeVar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write function that will set value from variable and then call she in another script.

```
//script1.js

var somevar;

function setSomevar(value){
somevar = value;
}

function getSomevar(){
return somevar;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('somelem').myPlugin();
});
```

Now you can call function setSomevar and pass the value to variable.
I hope that helps. Best Regards.

Comment: That's creating a global variable and altering the value from within a function.