# Access variable outside a script

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins

i have made a script which mixes colors. Now i want to convert that script into a plugin. I mainly have 3 var which will be as option to the user which is color1, color2, colorMix. 
The below code provides options to the user who uses the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Zepto(function($){
        var colorOptions = {
            color1: "rgb(53,119,187)",
            color2: "rgb(255,231,25)",
            colorMix: "rgb(118,190,69)"          
                      };
        $(document).colorScript(colorOptions);
    });
</script>
```

and the i call my plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colormix.js"></script>
```

and in my plugin,

```
Zepto(function($){
   $.fn.colorScript = function(options){
      alert(options.color1)
   }
});
```

Now i am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'colorScript'.

P.s : i was trying the script given on this question page [access javascript variable from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429229/access-javascript-variable-from-another-script)
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, you say "and the i call my plugin" but your plugin code should be executed before the actual usage.

Comment: why you usse Zepto ? remove that and try

Comment: @tsiki: i tried calling it before and it didn't work.

Comment: What was the error message that time?

Comment: Hey guys ive solved it atlast. I am using my companies script and that basically stops any scripts loading when specified outside the main index.html page. So when i referenced it in one of my pages, it didn't load. Now ive added my plugin on the main index.html page and everything works now. Really appreciate your quick responses guys.